# count the accumulated number of links in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I set up the environment where every tick, 3 pieces of information show up, and the turtles create links with them, meaning they integrate the information into their knowledge.

I'd like to count their accumulated knowledge with every tick.

But the problem is, the count function always count the number of all the existing links, not just the number of newly created links.

Of course, I can count properly when I make the links die, but that is not what I want.

What can I do?

```
directed-link-breed [infolinks infolink]
breed [guys guy]
breed [infobits infobit]
globals [newinfos x]

guy-own [knowledge]


to setup
ca
create-guys 2[
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
set knowledge random 100
set label knowledge
reset-ticks
end

to go
create-infobits 3[
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
ask guys [
set newinfos myself
expose newinfos
]]

ask guys 
[update-knowledge]
tick

end

to expose [new]
if random-float 1 < 0.8 [
create-infolink-to new
]

set x count infolink-neighbors
end

to update-knowledge
set knowledge knowledge + x 
set label knowledge
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a `guys-own` counter that is set to zero at each tick and then incremented every time a new link is made during that tick.  I've added such a counter, `new-knowledge` in the code below, and deleted the `globals` since they play no "global" role in your code as it stands.

```
directed-link-breed [infolinks infolink]
breed [guys guy]
breed [infobits infobit]
guys-own [knowledge new-knowledge]

to setup
  ca
  create-guys 2 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set knowledge random 100
    set label knowledge
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask guys [set new-knowledge 0]
  create-infobits 3 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ask guys [expose myself]
  ] 
  ask guys [update-knowledge]
  tick
  
end

to expose [new]
  if random-float 1 < 0.8 [
    create-infolink-to new
    set new-knowledge new-knowledge + 1
  ]
end

to update-knowledge
set knowledge knowledge + new-knowledge 
set label knowledge
end
```